# Pine Script arithmetic limit order

Tags: pine-script

Probably pretty simple answer, but I am trying to set my limit order to execute something like this

```
if ta.barssince(enterLong) < 3
    strategy.entry(id="EL", direction=strategy.long, limit=low[1] * -0.01)
```

i'm not sure how to write the arithmetic for this. Goal is to create a limit order based on prev candle trigger but to calculate limit by a negative in order to create a lower limit based on a percentage, so in this case, create limit entry at -1% from previous candle low.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't -1% in your logic is 99% of the whole value?

```
if ta.barssince(enterLong) < 3
    strategy.entry(id="EL", direction=strategy.long, limit=low[1] * 0.99)
```

Comment: i finally figured it out. it was the same as my stop loss calc but i was calling for a price from
strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - percCalc)
instead of
low[1] * (1 - percCalc)